# Best practices for authenticating Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

Django 4.1.4
djoser 2.1.0
channels 4.0.0

I have followed the documented recommendation for creating custom middleware to authenticate a user when using channels and I am successfully getting the user
and checking that the user is authenticated though I am sending the user ID in the querystring when connecting to the websocket to do this. The user is not automatically available in the websocket scope.

I am unsure if there are any potential security risks as the documentation mentions that their recommendation is insecure, I do check that the user.is_authenticated. So I believe I have secured it.

I do believe that using the token created by djoser would be better though I am not sure how to send headers with the websocket request unless I include the token in the querystring instead of the user's ID.

I am keen to hear what the best practices are.

I am passing the user ID to the websocket via querystring as follows at the frontend:

```
websocket.value = new WebSocket(`ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/marketwatch/? ${authStore.userId}`)
```

middleware.py

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(user_id):
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()
    else:
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return user
        else:
            return AnonymousUser()

class QueryAuthMiddleware:
    
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        
        scope['user'] = await get_user(int(scope["query_string"].decode()))

        return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
```

consumers.py

```
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

from api.middleware import QueryAuthMiddleware
from .routing import ws_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http':get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        QueryAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter(ws_urlpatterns)
        )
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some extensive research I decided not to pass the id or the token via the querystring as this poses a risk due to this data being stored in the server logs.

IMO the best option with the least amount of risk was passing the token as a message to the websocket after the connection was established and then verifying the token; closing the websocket if invalid.

This meant not requiring the middleware previously implemented. In this particular project no other messages would be received from the client so I don't need to do any checking on the key of the message received. This could be changed for chat apps and other apps that will receive further messages from the client.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
import json

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class MarketWatchConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    @database_sync_to_async
    def verify_token(self, token_dict):
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(key=token_dict['token'])
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        else: 
            if token.user.is_active:
                return True
            else:
                return False

   
    async def connect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_add('group', self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()
    

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        valid_token = await self.verify_token(json.loads(text_data))
        if not valid_token:
            await self.close()

        
    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard('group', self.channel_name)
```

Comment: Sorry, new to django. ain't no way to use POST instead of GET query string ? from a C# client.

Comment: Wouldn't it be quite risky to accept connection prior to authentication ?

Comment: @Ramzy But if you don't accept connection, how are you even gonna authenticate? User somehow needs to be connected to verify themself

Comment: You're correct, its a basic thing i missed.

Answer (score -1):

so your code should be a bit better here

```py
@database_sync_to_async
    def verify_token(self, token_dict):
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(key=token_dict['token'])
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        else: 
            if token.user.is_active:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

==>

```py
@database_sync_to_async
    def verify_token(self, token_dict):
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(key=token_dict['token'])
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        else: 
            return token.user.is_active
```